# Vertically center bootstrap dropdown menu icon in collapse mode

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, navbar

[image]

I've changed bootstrap navbar height and all other components in my navbar to center vertically to the new nav-bar height. I'm having trouble finding the css for the menu icon when the urls collapsed in the mobile mode.

Do you know how I can change the padding, margin for this menu icon on Bootstrap 3 navbar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this CSS when I changed my navbar height from the default 50px to 70px.

Looking at your screenshot, it looks like you just need to change the margin on the `.navbar-toggle` class from the default 8px to appropriate values for your new navbar height.

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/8gnPRqrILj

```
.navbar {
    min-height: 70px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 40px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 18px;
}
```